# How to automate the TeraTerm application

Tags: python, automation

I'd like to automate TeraTerm. I know how to open it, but don't know how to code the rest of it because I'm not familiar with Python syntax, particularly the Subprocesses module. How to select the serial and change the port?

code to open TeraTerm:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\teraterm\\ttermpro.exe"')
```

after execution of the above code tera term application will open but how to select "serial" and choose different port.

[image]

Comment: You can't do things like that with a process startup -- unless the application has command line options for the things you need. Instead of just python, you most likely need something that can click things on the screen.

Comment: Just take a look at the TeraTerm documentation?  All settings visible in your screenshot can be given on the commandline while starting up.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open some comport without using the GUI which means essentially you are trying to achieve the same using command line options which teraterm provides.
So you need to know them first.

```
import subprocess

def run():
    path=f'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\teraterm\\ttermpro.exe'
    comport=10
    Baudrate=115200
    process=subprocess.Popen(f'{path} /C={comport} /BAUD={Baudrate}',stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

run()
```

This will open your **COM10** on teraterm if it is connected to it via serial port else teraterm will throw an error. Cannot open COM10.Not found